# Can I use \sffamily inside \frac{}{}?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, sans-serif

I am having trouble writting `\sffamily` in `\frac{}{}`.

```
{$J$({\sffamily x}) $=$  {\sffamily x}$^{T}${\sffamily A}{\sffamily x} $/$ {\sffamily x}$^{T}${\sffamily B}}
```

I want to write it in `\frac`.

[image]

But it give error:

Comment: Why are you switching math on and off like that? just use `\mathsf{x}` and keep it all in math mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the suggestion of daleif in the comments, you can just use `\mathsf{x}` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section{In the section title as inline math
    $J(\mathsf{x}) =  \frac{\mathsf{x}^{T}\mathsf{A}\mathsf{x}}{\mathsf{x}^{T}\mathsf{B}}$
}
In normal body as displaied math
\[
    J(\mathsf{x}) =  \frac{\mathsf{x}^{T}\mathsf{A}\mathsf{x}}{\mathsf{x}^{T}\mathsf{B}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, can i use this in the title? `\section`?

Comment: sure you can! see the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

No, because `\sffamily` is a text-mode command, like `\textsf`.

If you want to use sans-serif variables consistently, you would be better off loading a sans-serif math font instead of putting `\mathsf` everywhere.  Options include a math package sch as `newtxsf`, Fira Math through `unicode-math`, `mathastext` and several `beamer` themes.

Assuming you do want upright sans-serif in only some cases, as others have said, the math-mode command is `\mathsf`.  You could also use `\textnormal{\sffamily ...}`.

Both `unicode-math` and the legacy `isomath` package also support an italic sans-serif alphabet, `\mathsfit`.  Both support sans-serif bold italic (`\mathbfsfit` in `unicode-math`, `\mathsfbfit` in `isomath`).

There are a few other options in `unicode-math`.  It has `\mathbfsfup` for bold upright sans-serif, and can select different fonts for `\symsf` and `\mathsf`, as well as for `\symsfit` and `\mathsfit`.  The former is intended for single-letter variables like in this example, and the latter for words and short phrases, such as `\mathsf{HYPOTENUSE}`.

If you need Greek sans-serif letters, you can get them in `isomath` with the `OMLmathsf` and `OMLmathsfit` options.  Unicode does not define mathematical Greek sans-serif letters, so `\symsfit\alpha` will not work, but you could get sans-serif Greek in `unicode-math` with `\setmathsf` or `\setmathfontface`.